# Microcode Problem

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, amd-processor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to load file, won’t boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229788/failed-to-load-file-wont-boot)

I recently got this error when trying to start up Ubuntu 12.10

microcode: failed to load file amd-ucode/microcode_amd.bin

It then starts up put I cant see any of the unity. I can however press ctrl+alt+t and get the command line to get up. How should I solve this?

Comment: You've already asked this question before: [Failed to load file, won't boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/229788/failed-to-load-file-wont-boot) I'm voting to close this one marking it as a duplicate. A moderator might want to merge the two questions. Please don't post your questions twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the missing package and reboot from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install amd64-microcode
sudo shutdown -r now
```